# Save survdiff output

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have run a `logrank` test with `survdiff` like below:

```
survdiff(formula = Surv(YearsToEvent, Event) ~ Cat, data = RegressionData)`
```

I get the following output:

```
                 N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
      0      30913      487    437.9      5.50      11.9
      1       3755       56     23.2     46.19      48.0
      2       3322       36     45.2      1.89       2.0
      3      15796      260    332.6     15.85      27.3

 Chisq= 71.9  on 3 degrees of freedom, p= 0.000000000000002
```

How can I save this (especially the p-value) to a .txt file? I am looping a bunch of regressions like this and want to save them all to a .text file.

Comment: ?capture.output is available. Also ?sink. Also look at code of its associated print function. Also look at structure of the results with ?str.